# Aplicativo não instala em modo release quando enviado para servidor

Tags: php, android, mime-type

Tenho uma instancia no Amazon EC2 no qual usando PHP faço *upload* de um APK. Criei um um *MIME-TYPE* mapeando o `.apk` com `application/vnd.android.package-archive`, e também editando o `.htaccess` inserindo um tipo desta forma abaixo:

```
AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk
```

O problema é que quando envio um `.apk` em modo *debug* funciona normalmente, porém quando faço *upload* da aplicação em modo *release*, faz o *download* corretamente, no entanto na hora da instalação exibe uma mensagem que não reconhece o pacote baixado.

Para fazer *upload* do arquivo uso o método [`move_upload_file`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.move-uploaded-file.php), desta forma abaixo:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'], $dir.$namefile)
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo? Existe alguma outra configuração que deve ser realizada na aplicação em modo release para que instale corretamente? É preciso fazer alguma configuração específica no envio do arquivo?